# How do i mount my internal hard disk when in "Try Ubuntu" mode?

Tags: windows, mount, drive

I am running the "Try Ubuntu" mode and I want to clear some of the data on the hard drive to install Ubuntu, but I cant access the hard drive at all, the hard drive works though. I am new to Linux and I want to know how to mount my `c: drive` on Ubuntu.

I put Ubuntu on a usb flash drive cause the laptop I have does not have a CD bay 
the Ubuntu menu came up as normal and i clicked "Install" and the it said that my hard drive doesn't have at least 5.9 GB available so I clicked "try Ubuntu" so i can run a command to clear the hard drive, I noticed that Ubuntu didn't mount the hard drive. I looked all over the Internet but nothing solves the problem.

Comment: From the GUI these days, you should have something simple like just double-clicking the hard drive. From the command-line, you'll need to use the standard `mount` command to mount `/dev/sda1` or whatever under `/mnt/sda1`, and then you should be able to navigate the mount point under `/mnt`. Have you done this already and are still having problems, or are you having problems getting to this point? Is your hard drive encrypted at all?

Comment: your question is vague, since you asked the installer to try it, of course you won't see it being installed in the disk.

Answer (score 1):

Open nautilus (File Manager), If you can see your partitions there just click on them and they will be mounted. They will be listed as 44 GB Drive, 70 GB Drive etc. Its better if you label up every drive.

[image]

If you want them to be auto mounted at startup you have to edit /etc/fstab. Search about fstab on Google.

Answer (score 0):

but in any case you can try to grep you disk from dmesg output.

```
dmesg | grep disk
```

this will list your disksize and partition names.
    fdisk -l /dev/diskname

```
mkdir /mnt/diska

mount /dev/partitionname /mnt/diska
```

Ubuntu should take care of your partition type.